# Find out UITableViewCellStyle from initWithCoder: or elsewhere

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to create a generic `UITableViewCell` subclass, which has a slightly different fonts for the `titleLabel` and `detailLabel` depending on the style of the cell being used.

Prior to using storyboard prototypes, this was alright, as I was using `initWithStyle:identifier:` however I've now updated the app to use the storyboard prototypes, which of course uses `initWithCoder:`

Is there a way I can find out the style of the cell that interface builder has set or can't this be done? I know I can override the text styles in IB itself, but I'd like to make it a bit more generic so I don't have to do that for every view